# How to escape the '@' symbol in bash?

Tags: bash, proxy, at-sign

I am trying to add my proxy with authentication parameters in bash, where my password contains an `@` symbol. The syntax to add proxy with authentication in bash is as follows:

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port_no/
```

Therefore, whenever I try to add a password with `@` in it, the applications that use this proxy try to connect to the string followed by the `@` symbol in the password.

For example, if my password is `p@ssword`, and the host is proxy.college.com, the applications try to connect to `ssword@proxy.college.com`.

I have tried escaping the `@` symbol using `\`, but this does has not solved.
How do I make this work without changing my password?

**Note:** This question is not similar to [How can i escape an arbitrary string for use as a command line argument in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306386/how-can-i-escape-an-arbitrary-string-for-use-as-a-command-line-argument-in-bash) nor [How to escape the at sign in bash](https://superuser.com/questions/183020/how-to-escape-the-at-sign-in-bash) since this specifically treats the '@' sign that comes up in commands where there is an `@` symbol already present and the `@` is used to delimit the given string into specific paramters.

**P.S.:** Though using the HTML code `%40` for `@` works, I would prefer a more readable method.

Comment: I'd change my password ;-)

Comment: Isn't that an unclean way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you need to write your login password that way? What application forces you to do that? it's probably a terrible security issue. Please read the `man` page of the application you're using, check that there's a possibility to send the password differently, or otherwise switch to another application.

Comment: Yes, I accept its a security issue, but most, including `apt-get` applications need the username and passwords in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` files. Others take it from the environment variables specified in `/etc/environment` or in `/home/$USER/.bashrc`. Though not a part of this question, I would readily accept other known, secure ways of doing this.

Comment: This is not a question about the shell (which does not require `@` to be escaped in this context), but about whatever program is using the `http_proxy` variable. If HTML encoding is the only way to get it to accept a literal `@`, that's what you'll have to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `%40` instead of an `@` sign.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention I wouldn't prefer using HTML codes, isn't there a way to escape this?