# Send an email in Perl to someone with apostrophe in the address

Tags: perl, shell, email

I am currently trying to write an email in Perl to a user who has an apostrophe in it and can not figure out how to get it to send. Here is what the line looks like:

```
$to = "o'connell\@website.com";
```

Here is the line I use to send the email:

```
system("echo $message | mailx -s $subject $to ");
```

This is an example email of `o'connell@website.com`. It will not send it because of the apostrophe. I have tried the following and it hasn't worked. I am using `mailx` to send the email

```
$to = "o'connell\@website.com";
$to = "o''connell\@website.com";
$to = "o"'"connell\@website.com";
```

None of these worked. I can send an email to somebody who doesn't have it in their email though. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you send the email? What library do you use?

Comment: I use mailx to send them

Comment: Well, you can 'specify' the email via `my $to = q{o'connell@website.com};` - there's no guarantee the mailserver will accept it though.

Comment: Interesting. What does the q mean?

Comment: @user081608 Could you post the error message you receive?  It is important which part of email delivery pipeline rejects the address.

Comment: `mailx`? You mean you call `system` or backticks?

Comment: I am actually not getting an error message from the error checking i have set up. Thats what is confusing me. I can send an email to everyone else besides someone with an apostrophe in it. I will post the mailx line in the top that i send the email with.

Comment: The problem's not the Perl string - it's getting it escaped properly for your shell, since you're piping into it via `system`. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306386/how-can-i-escape-an-arbitrary-string-for-use-as-a-command-line-argument-in-bash

Comment: @Sobrique shouldn't that be `qw`?

Comment: You've shown the value you put in a variable.  Please show what you do with that variable (e.g., **how** you pass it to mailx) to send the email.  "I am actually not getting an error message from the error checking i have set up" doesn't mean a lot if we don't see the error checking you have set up.

Comment: No. I meant what I said. `q{}` is a quote operator _like_ `qw` but it's not the same. It's comparable to single quotes `'`.

Comment: @MaxLybbert I posted above the system call I use to send the mail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a Perl problem, it's a shell problem. You have to escape the values properly:

```
system("echo $message | mailx -s $subject \"$to\" ");
```

or, more readable:

```
system qq(echo $message | mailx -s $subject "$to");
```

I'd escape the subject, too, and you should be very careful about $message, as well - what if it contained

```
; rm -rf /
```

See [Task::Kensho::Email](http://p3rl.org/Task::Kensho::Email) on how to send email from Perl directly.

Comment: Interesting I did not think about that. So would I just set $to = "o'connell@website.com" with that format in system?

Comment: The first system call you used fixed the issue but the second one did not work correctly. Should that be a single q?

Comment: @user081608 If you do `$to = "o'connell@website.com";` with double quotes and you're not using strict, `@website` will be interpolated as an (empty) array, so you're actually setting the value of `$to` to `o'connell.com`. Use `$to = q{o'connell@website.com};` instead (and always `use strict; use warnings;`).

Comment: @user081608 No, it should be `qq`, and both of those snippets should do exactly the same thing. `qq` interpolates variables while `q` doesn't. See the section on [quote-like operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) in `perldoc perlop`.

Comment: That's still no good. An email address can legitimately contain `"`.

Answer (score 3):

You may make perl execute mailx directly without shell "in between".
[ Take a look at simpler implementation in [wdebeaum answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31542950/2139766) ]

```
$message="message\n";
$to='$to = 'o\'connell\@website.com';
$subject= "x's " . time(); # string with apostrophe and time mark for testing
```

# separator to make stackoverflow syntax coloring work after confusion above

```
if( my $child_pid = open(my $TO_KID,   "|-")) {
   # I am the parent:
   print $TO_KID $message;
   close($TO_KID);
   waitpid $child_pid, 0;
} elsif(defined($child_pid)) {
   # I am the child; use STDIN/STDOUT normally
   exec 'mailx','-s',$subject,$to;
   die "couldn't exec mailx: $!";
}else{
   # $child_pid is undefined - fork (in open) failed
   die "can't fork: $!";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Like Andrzej, I'd say avoid using the shell. But there's a simpler way to accomplish that:

```
open(FH, "|-", "mailx", "-s", $subject, $to) or die "Can't mailx: $!";
print FH $message;
close(FH);
```

If you give the command and its arguments to open with the "|-" mode, `open` and `close` will handle the `exec`ing and `waitpid`ing for you.

From `perldoc -f open`:

> ```
>          The following blocks are more or less equivalent:
>
>             open(FOO, "|tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'");
>             open(FOO, "|-", "tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'");
>             open(FOO, "|-") || exec 'tr', '[a-z]', '[A-Z]';
>             open(FOO, "|-", "tr", '[a-z]', '[A-Z]');
>
>             open(FOO, "cat -n '$file'|");
>             open(FOO, "-|", "cat -n '$file'");
>             open(FOO, "-|") || exec "cat", "-n", $file;
>             open(FOO, "-|", "cat", "-n", $file);
>
>         The last two examples in each block show the pipe as "list form",
>         which is not yet supported on all platforms. A good rule of thumb
>         is that if your platform has a real "fork()" (in other words, if
>         your platform is Unix, including Linux and MacOS X), you can use
>         the list form. You would want to use the list form of the pipe so
>         you can pass literal arguments to the command without risk of the
>         shell interpreting any shell metacharacters in them. However, this
>         also bars you from opening pipes to commands that intentionally
>         contain shell metacharacters, such as:
>
>             open(FOO, "|cat -n | expand -4 | lpr")
>                 // die "Can't open pipeline to lpr: $!";
>
>         See "Safe Pipe Opens" in perlipc for more examples of this.
> ```

...

> ```
>         Closing any piped filehandle causes the parent process to wait for
>         the child to finish, then returns the status value in $? and
>         "${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE}".
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You are improperly building the shell command. Use the following:

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd1 = shell_quote('echo', $message);
my $cmd2 = shell_quote('mailx', '-s', $subject, $to);
system("$cmd1 | $cmd2");
```

But you can avoid using `echo` and involving a shell by using the following:

```
open(my $pipe, "|-", "mailx", "-s", $subject, $to)
   or die("Can't execute mailx: $!\n");
print($pipe $message);
close($pipe);
```

Even better would be to use a module designed to help you send emails.